# How to Update List of Account in visualforcepage?

Tags: apex, visualforce, date

Iam new at salesforce, anf need your help and advice guys.
there is a list of account objec and I want to update PPDDate field (custom type date).
i can update several PPDDate at once then press the update button to update all changes. this is the ilustration
[image]

But PPDDate is not updated.
this is my code now

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="SelectAll">
    <script>
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
        var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        alert('Successfully Set Data'+ inputCheckBox.length);
        for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){
            if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1) {  
                inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                //inputCheckBox[i].disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountList}" var="acc"  id="AccountTable">
                <apex:column headerValue="Action" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">
                        <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')" >
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="AccountTable"/>
                        </apex:inputCheckbox>
                    </apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="inputId" value="{!acc.id}" >
                         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange"/>
                    </apex:inputCheckbox>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Account Name" >
                    {!acc.name}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Phone" >
                    {!acc.phone}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Type" >
                    {!acc.type}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Date" >
                     <apex:inputField type="date" value="{!acc.PPD_Date__c}">
                         <apex:actionSupport event="onblur" reRender="">
                         </apex:actionSupport>
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!saveall}" value="Save All"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

apex code:

```
public class SelectAll {
    public List<Account> accountList {get;set;}

    public SelectAll ()
    {
        init();
    }
    
   public void init() {
      accountList = [select id,name,phone,AccountSource,type,CreatedDate,PPD_Date__c from Account];   
   }    
    
    public PageReference saveAll(){      
        try{ 
            update accountList;          
        }
        catch(DmlException ex){
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
        }
        init();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple solution that uses most of the standard salesforce classes.

On your custom controller, make use of `StandardSetController` by feeding it the query to benefit from pagination, get records, and save mechanism without any further implementation.

On the visual force page markup use the  `<apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}"/>` inside  `<apex:column headerValue="Name">`. The *input field* is a read/write element, when you change its values it will automatically update the `StandandardSetController` respective record. For the save command, you can invoke the *standardSetController* save method.

Below the minimum example:

// AccountsListController

```
public class AccountsListController {
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc{
        get{
            if(ssc == null){
                 ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10]));
            }
            return ssc;
        }
        set;
    }
    
    public List<Account> getAccounts(){
       return (List<Account>) ssc.getRecords();
    }
    
    public PageReference save(){
        ssc.save();
        return null;
    }
}
```

// AccountsList vfp

```
<apex:page controller="AccountsListController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc" id="AccountTable">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                     <apex:inputField value="{!acc.name}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save All"/>
        
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]